# How can i create a video overlay?

Tags: java, php, javascript, html, overlay

Hi i have seen a few blogs that doe this but i was wondering how they got it done, I don't know exactly what to look up concerning this.

Check out this link http://concreteloop.com/2013/02/video-nicki-minaj-french-montanas-freaks-behind-the-scenes

notice that they have an image and a playbutton, and once you click the play button, the image disappears and the video plays. I was wondering if anyone knows where i can learn to create this function.

Comment: I doubt you are going to get much help here by linking to a nicki minaj video.  Why can't you view the page source and see what is going on? Or ask a real question.

Comment: Right click on the page while browsing on chrome, then click inspect element! Voila...

Comment: @jzworkman no need to be rude about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple sample of what you're trying to achieve. Having the video initially hidden, and then shown and played when the user clicks on the image.

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://content.internetvideoarchive.com/content/photos/7142/29998006_.jpg" />
    <video width="320" height="240" controls style="display: none;">
        <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('img').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            $('video').show()
            $('video')[0].play();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dumbest way I would do it, would be to have a image file and a js function linked to it that basically hides the image on click and shows a div block containing the video. Though you really need to learn to use firebug or web inspector.